# where is the path of opConfig.reloadPrice(); in magento

Tags: magento

i need to customize function opConfig.reloadPrice(); in magento.

can anyone tell me where is that function locate?

This function is executed on custom attribute drop down on product details page.

As i need to change the Special price calculation , i guess need to customize this function .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method can be found in following files:

```
grep 'reloadPrice:' . -rsn
./js/varien/configurable.js:271:    reloadPrice: function()
./js/varien/product.js:463:    reloadPrice: function()
./skin/frontend/base/default/js/bundle.js:83:    reloadPrice: function()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to you for help.

i have a product .
regular price:     1000
Special Price:     500

So the discounted % is 50%, now whenever i am selecting the attribute box for left eye and right eye for 1box each +500

so it should be Regular price: 1000+500+500 = 2000
and Special price should be: 1000

But it's giving us Special Price : 1500

How can i fix it?

Comment: sorry dude you have to describe your task better or no one will understand them and nobody will do the work for you here

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284972/magento-special-price-problem

Answer (score 3):

For change custom option value, you should change in to js/varient/product.js

and in that page you found, reload:function()

that function call at the time of on change event.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue of having to change the default behaviour of Magento on this one. I included jQuery in my project and I finaly figured it out by first removing the default behavior of Magento and instead on calculatePrice call my `calculatePrices()`-function:

```
$j('#select_20, #select_21').removeAttr('onchange').change(function(){
    calculatePrices();
});
```

Now, in this `calculatePrices()`-function, alongside with some other logic, I included this to change the prices:

```
function calculatePrices()
{
    var price = 0;

    // some logic with custom options, not interesting for this question...

    // Change the price according to the options:
    $j('#select_20, #select_21').each(function(){
        var selectId = this.id.replace('select_', '');
        var options = opConfig.config[selectId][this.value];
        if(options.type == 'fixed') {
            price += options.priceValue;
        } else {
            // percentual change:
            price += price * (options.priceValue/100);
        }
    });

    // Use Magento Objects to set these prices:
    optionsPrice.changePrice('bundle', price);
    optionsPrice.reload();
}
```